# Scala TypeTags and performance

Tags: scala

There are some answers around for equivalent questions about Java, but is scala reflection (2.11, TypeTags) really slow? there's a long narrative write-up about it at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html, where the answer to this question is hard to extract.

I see a lot of advice floating around about avoiding reflection, maybe some of it predating the improvements of 2.11, but if this works well it looks like it can solve the debilitating aspect of the JVM's type erasure, for scala code.

Thanks!

Comment: Calling a method via reflection (in Java or Scala) is much slower than calling the method directly, because more work has do be done at runtime - finding the method, resolving it etc. so if it's not necessary, don't use reflection.

Comment: Are you addressing the case of looking up an object's methods and then calling one? how would it relate to typetags or type recovery?

Comment: Can you provide some example of TypeTags usage, where you are concerned about performance? Some usage is fast, some is slow, answer discussing each possible usage seems hard to expect (would be too long).

Answer (score 7):

Let's measure it.
I've created simple `class C` that has one method. All what this method do is sleep for 10ms.
Let's invoke this method

- within reflection
- directly

And see which is faster and how fast it is.

I've created three tests.

*Test 1.* Invoke via reflection. Execution time include all work that necessary to be done for setup reflection.
Create `runtimeMirror`, reflect class, create declaration for method, and at last step - execute method.

*Test 2.* Do not take into account this preparation stage, as it can be re-used.
We are calculate time of method invoking via reflection only.

*Test 3.* Invoke method directly.

**Results:**

> Reflection from start :  job done in 2561ms got 101 (1,5seconds for setup each execution)
>
> Invoke method reflection:  job done in 1093ms got 101 ( < 1ms for setup each execution)
>
> No reflection:  job done in 1087ms got 101  ( < 1ms for setup each execution)

**Conclusion:**
Setup phase increase execution time dramatically. But there are no need to perform setup on each execution (this is like class initialization - can be done once). So if you use reflection in right way(with separated init stage) it shows relevant performance and can be used for production.

**Source code:**

```
    class C {
      def x = {
        Thread.sleep(10)
        1
      }
    }


    class XYZTest extends FunSpec {
      def withTime[T](procName: String, f: => T): T = {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val r = f
        val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
        print(s"$procName job done in ${end-start}ms")
        r
      }

      describe("SomeTest") {
        it("rebuild each time") {
          val s = withTime("Reflection from start : ", (0 to 100). map {x =>
            val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
            val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
            val im = m.reflect(new C)
            val methodX = ru.typeOf[C].declaration(ru.TermName("x")).asMethod
            val mm = im.reflectMethod(methodX)
            mm().asInstanceOf[Int]
          }).sum
          println(s" got $s")
        }
        it("invoke each time") {
          val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
          val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
          val im = m.reflect(new C)
          val s = withTime("Invoke method reflection: ", (0 to 100). map {x =>
            val methodX = ru.typeOf[C].declaration(ru.TermName("x")).asMethod
            val mm = im.reflectMethod(methodX)
            mm().asInstanceOf[Int]
          }).sum
          println(s" got $s")
        }
        it("invoke directly") {
          val c = new C()
          val s = withTime("No reflection: ", (0 to 100). map {x =>
            c.x
          }).sum
          println(s" got $s")
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This answer has been very helpful in the overall. Any connection to TypeTags?

Comment: `typeOf[C]` uses `TypeTag`s. Generally, it very much depends on what you actually need to do with them. Some operations _are_ going to be slow.

Comment: @Mr.V. I'd recommend reading about how to benchmark JVM operations. In particular, look into JMH, or ScalaMeter.

Comment: I agree, my benchmark is not very precise. Moreover there are no warmup phase so first method takes more cause of it. But in general I decided not to fix it as it does not conceptually change results: reflection can work as fast as direct calls.